# How to efficiently use memory in google colab?

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory, video-processing

I am currently training a audio-visual model in google colab. I am using the "VoxCeleb" dataset. I am trying to extract the frames from the dataset and also the audio and use them as inputs for my deep learning model. My colab has been constantly crashing while training. Can anybody check out my code. I am pretty new to deep learning and colab so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the link to my colab - https://colab.research.google.com/github/kaneelgit/msi_voxceleb/blob/main/Multimodal_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=AOF5ENJXocup

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 million trainable parameters; you can not train such a big model in colab/kaggle. From my experience, I have run up to 1 million parameters in colab. Please decrease your model complexity, or better use a pre-trained model to featurise your data then customize that to incorporate your model.